# Log.txt file locked, gets too large

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, filesize, filelock

I'm running NiceHash's latest version, there's a dialog that's saved to a log.txt file. It gets large enough to crash windows, if not stopped, so I wrote a batch file with the following:

```
forfiles -p C:\Users\CBRocks\AppData\Roaming\nhm2\logs /m log* /c "cmd /c if @fsize gtr 50000000 del @path"
```

Which deletes the log file. Killing the excavator and forcing NiceHash to restart.

I'd like to write something to delete the oldest 90% of the text, but it's locked by the excavator, manually deleting and saving is a fail message. (problem1)

It looks like I'm not  going to be able to do it with command shell though (problem2), so before I go off learning C++ or so, is there a way to edit [sometext] to [""] in a file with an open lock file?

this is a recurring string:

```
"time":"2018-01-23T03:00:30.238Z"
```

I think I can use it to delete text where the timestamp is more than 00:30:00 earlier than that, I would like to call a batch file to do the text editing/file saving instead of deleting the file. I'm going to have to load an editor though, or point the command shell at some text functions that already exist for Windows 10 64-bit.

Do-able?

Suggestions for an easy-to-use batchfile editor?

Comment: rolling log file appender on size is no option in your logging framework?

Comment: If the file is locked by another application, there's no programming language that can unlock it for you.  The process that holds the lock has to release it. This sounds like a bug or design flaw in whatever is writing to that log file.

Comment: @jwdonahue - you can close open handles from other processes given you have the rights to do so but I leave it to OP to consider it being a good idea *(disclaimer: it's not!)*. I totaly agree on this being a bug or design flaw *(or misconfiguration from OP)*

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, Oh of course, some operating systems have utilities and API's to muck around with just about anything on the system.  But those usually aren't programming language specific and should not be used without a clear understanding how they work and what the problem is that they are trying to solve.  The OP seemed to be in search of a magic spell, rather than focusing on the actual problem.

Comment: thanks to @LievenKeersmaekers and Patrick Artner for your answers, I will look into other ways to handle this, Patrick, it looks like the logging software does start new files. Left to itself, that is still a problem. JW, you are correct, it is a problem with the app design